# recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create() AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'face'

Tags: python, opencv

At this line recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()  i'm getting an error cv2.cv2 module has no attribute 'face'. I already tried uninstalling and reinstall opencv contrib but i still get the error.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import os

# Path for face image database
path = '/home/pi/FacialRecognitionProject/dataset/'

recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
detector = cv2.CascadeClassifier("/home/pi/FacialRecognitionProject/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml");

# function to get the images and label data
def getImagesAndLabels(path):

    imagePaths = [os.path.join(path,f) for f in os.listdir(path)]     
    faceSamples=[]
    ids = []

    for imagePath in imagePaths:

        PIL_img = Image.open(imagePath).convert('L') # convert it to grayscale
        img_numpy = np.array(PIL_img,'uint8')

        id = int(os.path.split(imagePath)[-1].split(".")[1])
        faces = detector.detectMultiScale(img_numpy)

        for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
            faceSamples.append(img_numpy[y:y+h,x:x+w])
            ids.append(id)

    return faceSamples,ids

print ("\n [INFO] Training faces. It will take a few seconds. Wait ...")
faces,ids = getImagesAndLabels(path)
recognizer.train(faces, np.array(ids))

# Save the model into trainer/trainer.yml
recognizer.write('/home/pi/FacialRecognitionProject/trainer/trainer.yml') # recognizer.save() worked on Mac, but not on Pi

# Print the numer of faces trained and end program
print("\n [INFO] {0} faces trained. Exiting Program".format(len(np.unique(ids))))
```

Comment: Did you compile the face detection module (`BUILD_opencv_face`), assuming you compiled OpenCV yourself? How did you install OpenCV? `cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()` works on my system (OpenCV installed via anaconda).

Comment: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/26/install-opencv-4-on-your-raspberry-pi/   followed this steps.

Comment: I'm working on my raspberry pi

Comment: Please do not use that and use the pre-built wheel that's specifically for the RPi: https://www.piwheels.org/project/opencv-contrib-python/.  You are getting this error because the OpenCV contrib library is not part of your OpenCV version.  `sudo apt install libcairo-gobject2 libwebp6 libilmbase23 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libjasper1 libpango-1.0-0 libavcodec58 libavutil56 libqt4-test libqtgui4 libcairo2 libswscale5 libatk1.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libqtcore4 libtiff5 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libavformat58 libopenexr23`, then `sudo pip3 install opencv-contrib-python`.

Comment: yes i tried pip install opencv-contrib-python, still the same

Comment: Please update pip and then install as `pip install opencv-python opencv-contrib-python --user` this will keep both the packages integrated. I also tried other ways but this is the correct way as all the other dependencies will be installed automatically. Hope this will resolve the issue of module 'face' from library 'opencv-contrib-python'